# In Eclipse, how to refactor anonymous interface implementation to Enum Singleton

Tags: java, eclipse, interface, enums, refactoring

Let's say I have an interface:

```
public interface Foo{
    String bar(int baz);
}
```

Now in some Java code I have an anonymous implementation of that interface:

```
Foo foo = new Foo(){
    public String bar(int baz){
        return String.valueOf(baz);
    }
};
```

Is there a way (in Eclipse) to refactor this to the enum singleton pattern (Effective Java, Item 3), like this:

```
// further up in the same Compilation Unit:
enum StandardFoo implements Foo{
    INSTANCE{
        public String bar(int baz){
            return String.valueOf(baz);
        }
    }
}

// ...
Foo foo = StandardFoo.INSTANCE;
```

This refactoring is tedious to do by hand and I do it all the time. Is there any plugin that does that? Or a secret JDT trick I don't know about (I'm using Indigo)?

BTW: do Idea or NetBeans support this refactoring?

Comment: I'm a little surprised you find yourself doing this "all the time."  Is Singleton really what you want here, particularly if it's only used in that class?

Comment: @Mark a) once it's in this class, I can easily refactor it to an extra class if I wish to (but ideally a refactoring solution would ask me, like the "New class..." wizard). b) It makes sense when programming in a slightly functional way, e.g. when using Guava's `Function` and `Supplier` interfaces.

Comment: But those things have absolutely no need of being a singleton.  Why do you need to enforce it?

Comment: @Mark I would want to make them constants anyway (to save on Object allocations), so using an enum seems the natural choice to me (because of the nice additional features like being a compile-time constant, de-serialization safety etc. It's also a documentation of intent for a stateless style of developing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDEA supports [Structural Search and Replace](http://tv.jetbrains.net/videocontent/intellij-idea-static-analysis-custom-rules-with-structural-search-replace) (Tutorial), which I believe could speed this up for you.

Comment: Wow, this is awesome. I don't know if this would help for this particular refactoring and I'm certainly not going to switch from Eclipse (mostly because of the STS), but I'm impressed!

Comment: For the record: about a year later, I did switch to IntelliJ, and this was one of the main reasons :-)

Answer (score 2):

There is no way.

btw, it would be more usual to do something like this:

```
enum StandardFoo implements Foo {
    INSTANCE1(0),
    INSTANCE2(5);

    private final int delta;

    private StandardFoo(int delta) {
        this.delta = delta;
    }

    public String bar(int baz) {
        // Simple example to demonstrate using fields in enum methods
        return String.valueOf(baz + delta); 
    }
}
```

FYI even though they are defined as "INSTANCE1(0)", you still refer to them as just "INSTANCE1" in code; ie `StandardFoo.INSTANCE1.bar(123)` etc

Perhaps adding a private field to the enum to assist with the implementation of the method, set via a (private) constructor.

Comment: That doesn't really look like a singleton.  You're right though, unless you **are** going to make it a multiton with different implementations of `bar` there's not much point in anonymously "subclassing" `StandardFoo`.

Comment: I don't get the purpose of your example. When you have more than one enum item, either field values or implementation methods should differ. Otherwise what's the point of having more than one item in the first place? To be clear: in 90% of the cases I am talking about I only need one enum item, but it's easy enough to add more once the enum is there.

Comment: I've edited the answer to demonstrate why it could make sense. It does presume a sharing of logic - just like a normal class when different instances have different field values and behave differently because of that

Comment: @Bohemian now it makes sense (+1), but unfortunately it doesn't answer my actual question

Answer (score 2):

The refactoring "Convert anonymous class to nested" does a part of the trick. You have to change the class into an enum and replace the ctor call by the enum singleton.

Comment: Hello Heiko, welcome and thanks for your answer. But, I'm aware of this and frankly: with all that twiddling I have to do, it doesn't save me any time compared to just doing it myself.